# ndf file missing error shown while attaching the "mdf" file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There was a space issue for a database in our server. So we added a secondary file (ndf file) for that DB in another drive. (ndf file- 'c' drive, mdf,ldf file- 'e' drive). When we formatted the 'C' drive, the ndf file got deleted. When we try to get that DB back again by attaching the 'mdf' file, we are getting error that "ndf file is missing".
SO what can we do next to get that DB back again to its old state?

Comment: Simple solution: Shadow back your .ndf file and retrieve it :). or create a back database and attach .bak file if one available.

Comment: back file is not available . I tried creating a new database and adding a new ndf file. after that i tried to replace the new mdf annd ldf file with the old mdf and ldf file after stopping the sql server service. Then i restart the service. Now i couldn't access the database. its showing "Database is in recovery mode"

Comment: Is this helping? http://www.sqlnotes.info/2013/05/07/attach-database-with-missing-ndf-file/

Comment: Your database is essentially dead. You can try `DBCC CHECKDB` with `REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`, but even if this works, any data that was actually in the .NDF file (if any) is obviously gone no matter what. These (and other disasters) are essentially what you make backups for.

Comment: I completely agree with @JeroenMostert, the best way is to shadow back your .ndf file. Ask your it ops to retrieve this.

Answer (score 3):

This is a totally bad move all the way round. First its a bad practice to put database files on the C: drive. Secondly, in the attempt to format C: drive which basically includes rebuilding the server; why would you not perform a backup of entire server or at least files on the server.

Your resolution in this scenario is very very limited and sorry if it comes out harsh but take this as a IT/life lesson. Some data is so much very important that I cant imagine having to lose it.Okay now these are the options that I see:

- Use a data recovery tool to try and retrieve the formatted disk data. This is not a guaranteed process anyways.
- Once you have your .ndf file, you should be able restore file - hopefully is not corrupted.
- If retrieved .NDF file is corrupted or cannot be retrieved; then be ready to accept data loss. You can attempt `DBCC CHECKDB` with `REPAR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`. Note this command is not a guaranteed fix for the database
- If all the above options do not work. There is a great third party tool called [Stellar Phoenix SQL Database Repair](https://www.stellarinfo.com/database-recovery.php) that can repair .MDF and .NDF files. It will repair and recovery data from corrupted database files which can then be exported into other formats including a newly created database. I really think this would be your best solution if you need to stand up this database again.

Good luck and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

ndf file contains the data and ndf file is copy where your file is

Comment: It's unclear how this answers the question, which seems to assert that "ndf" is two things.